# Browse, List and Delete files with qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-designer

I have created the following form with qt designer.
I added a Add Files button that works with QDir and QFileDialog and loads files into a listWidget.

[image]

Here are my methods that fill this form with the files.

```
void RightDoneIt::changeDirectory()
{
/* select a directory using file dialog */
    QString path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory (this, tr("Directory"), directory.path());
    if ( path.isNull() == false )
    {
        directory.setPath(path);
        fillList();
    }
}


/*get list of file from given directory and the append it to listWidget */
void RightDoneIt::fillList()
{
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget->addItems(directory.entryList());



}
```

I would like to modified my code so I can list the file location and the file size next to the file name and also to make this remove files button working.

I just want to be able to choose files using ctrl or command key(for macs) and press delete to remove these files from my list.

Do i have to use a QtreeWidget instead of listwidget ?

What are the best practices for doing that ?

any code suggestions ?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just listing files (no folder and subfolder structure), you don't need a `QTreeWidget`.

But as you are willing to show the file location and file size, I would use a `QTableWidget` (or `QTableView`).

However, I would suggest to have a look at [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfilesystemmodel.html). Depending on what you're trying to do you with your app, this class might come handy : You can use this model and display it in a view widget.

And `QFileSystemModel` comes with methods such as [remove()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfilesystemmodel.html#remove) and will also handle file renaming.

Comment: Hi Jerome, I meant to delete files from the list not from the system.